# \printbiblist{shorteditor}: how to print this field as a label?

Tags: biblatex

Am I wrong in assuming that the following should print the `shorteditor` field contents as leading label in the bibliography list?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose-inote]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BookInBook{Lit,
  title =    {Deuxième livre des Épidémies},
  date =     1846,
  author =   {Hippocrate},
  booktitle =    {Œuvres complètes d'Hippocrate},
  editor =   {Littré, Émile},
  shorteditor =  {Littré},
  volume =   {\RN{5}},
  entrysubtype = {editiones},
  publisher =    {J.-B. Baillère},
  location =     {Paris},
  pages =    {72--139}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbiblist[title={Editiones uel studia}]{shorteditor}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make full use of `\printbiblist{<label>}` you need at least a bibliography environment `<label>` and a driver `<label>`. For some fields `biblatex` provides useful fallback definitions, but not for `shorteditor`.

For the MWE below I just copied the definitions for `shorthand` from the standard styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose-inote]{biblatex}

\defbibenvironment{shorteditor}
  {\list
     {\printnames{shorteditor}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{1cm}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{shorteditor}{%
  \usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
    {\thefield{entrytype}}%
  \finentry}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BookInBook{Lit,
  title        = {Deuxième livre des Épidémies},
  date         = 1846,
  author       = {Hippocrate},
  booktitle    = {Œuvres complètes d'Hippocrate},
  editor       = {Littré, Émile},
  shorteditor  = {Littré},
  volume       = {\RN{5}},
  entrysubtype = {editiones},
  publisher    = {J.-B. Baillère},
  location     = {Paris},
  pages        = {72--139},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbiblist[title={Editiones uel studia}]{shorteditor}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Biblist and bibliography]

One problem here is that you won't get automatic label width calculation for `shorteditor` and have to hardcode the label width (I chose 1cm), since `biblatex`'s label width calculations don't support name fields.

In this case I think it would not be necessary to use a `shorteditor` in the first place: After all the `shorteditor` can just be obtained from the `editor` field by just dropping the given name.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer!  I know that using `shorthand` for example would be more sensible, but what is wished is to print a list of critical editions used as sources for mentioning scholars responsible for previous emendations in the apparatus criticus of a new edition.  What is needed is to refer to scholars and list them all by name ahead of the edition text.  But in the commentary, the same books are referred  to by means of a shorthand.  Therefore both are used...  But how do you drop the given name?

Comment: @RobertAlessi I didn't want to claim that `shorthand` would be more sensible here, I tried to say that in this example the `shorteditor` just duplicates info from the `editor` field. In theory it would be possible to just not have a `shorteditor` field and do everything only with `editor`. Whether that is sensible in your real document, I don't know.

Comment: Yes, I got your point as I was reaching the end of my comment.  But with such a field as `editor = {Littré, Émile}`, how do I get only `Littré` in specific places?  Is it by specifying a formatting directive in the fourth argument of `\citename` and so also in the definition of the driver or the environment?

Comment: @RobertAlessi You need a new name format and can use the optional argument to `\printnames`. https://gist.github.com/moewew/63a83448ba89600dcfc8157c213fbf7f shows how this could work in the MWE.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I owe you a new page to appear in the documentation of the next release of the `ekdosis` package.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of `\printbiblist` is simply a label used to identify, for example, a bibliography driver. If you want a list of all the entries with a `shorteditor` field you have to define a new driver:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{shorteditor}{%
  \printnames{shorteditor}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{booktitle}%
  % other fields
  }
```

and then use:

```
\printbiblist[title={Editiones uel studia}]{shorteditor}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I must have misunderstood what is a `Label field`.  See the documentation on p. 25 for `shorteditor` and 94 at the bottom, where it is said that `biblatex` provides automatic support for fields marked as `Label fields`.  I tried with `shorttitle` and it worked without having to define a new driver.